# Flutter: Implementing Pagination using Firebase Realtime Database with http request

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, httprequest

How can I implement pagination in Realtime Database using an HTTP request in Flutter? I tried the following but it returned an error.

```
  Future<List<News>> fetchNews() async {
    final response = await http.get("https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com/posts.json?orderBy='t'&limitToFirst=10");
    Map map = json.decode(response.body);
    map.forEach((NewsId, NewsData) {
      _list.add(News.fromJson(NewsData));
    });
    return _list;
  }
```

The error returned was:

```
I/flutter (18683): {
I/flutter (18683):   "error" : "orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"
I/flutter (18683): }
```

I tried to replace the url with this:[https://project-id.firebaseio.com/posts.json?orderBy=(backslash)"t(backslash)"&limitToFirst=10](https://project-id.firebaseio.com/posts.json?orderBy=(backslash)%22t(backslash)%22&limitToFirst=10)
but the error I received was this:

```
I/flutter (18683): {
I/flutter (18683):   "error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"t\", for path \"/posts\", to the rules"
I/flutter (18683): }
```

Any help on how to implement pagination would be helpful. I don't mind reverting back to using the package instead of the http request either. If there are any significant differences between either of the methods, I would appreciate some information on that.

My database structure is the following:

```
<project-id>
|__posts
     |____(unique key1)
               |_____field1
               |_____field2
               |_____field3
     |____(unique key2)
     |____(unique key3)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. The first error is because the property name to order on must be a string in double quotes. Single quotes are not acceptable, so your way of escaping the `"` is indeed correct.

The new error is because you need to define an index in the security rules for your database, so that the server knows what to sort/filter the database on. If you check the documentation on [indexing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) and take the information from your error message, that turns into:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      ".indexOn": "t"
    }
  }
}
```

By the way: I usually first get my REST queries working in the browser, and only then replicate them in my code. That way you know whether the error comes from Firebase, or from the way you're calling it in your Flutter code.